# ¿Cómo mostrar/ocultar adecuadamente una opción de menú de forma programática en Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Quiero mostrar/ocultar una opción de menú en la barra superior mediante programación desde un fragmento.

Hay dos situaciones posibles:

1. En las preferencias el usuario indica que no desea utilizar esa opción. En ese caso, la opción no aparecerá en el menú de la barra superior. Aquí no hay ningún problema, la opción del menú de por sí no es visible y punto.
2. En las preferencias el usuario indica que quiere utilizar esa opción. En ese caso, la opción aparecerá en el menú de la barra superior. Y aquí es donde tengo el problema que explico a continuación.

Cuando se abre el fragmento compruebo el estado de esa opción en las preferencias y si el usuario ha indicado que quiere usar esa opción, la muestro, para ello uso el método `setPlayerButton()` que verán más abajo. Se trata de una opción de lectura de texto a voz. También, quiero ocultar la opción en el menú de la barra superior cuando hay una lectura en curso.

Todo funciona bien, pero **solo la primera vez**. Es decir, la primera vez que entro al fragmento, si la opción en las preferencias está activada, puedo ver el botón en el menú y puedo usarlo sin problemas y también puedo ocultarlo cuando está sucediendo una lectura de voz y mostrarlo de nuevo cuando la lectura se detiene.

Esta es una captura de pantalla de mi barra superior la primera vez que cargo el fragmento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ya dije, en una primera carga del fragmento todo funciona como esperado. Pero los problemas vienen cuando interactúo desde el fragmento.

Por ejemplo, si elijo la opción de Calendario (icono a la derecha de play), esta opción me carga otro fragmento donde hay un calendario desde el cual yo puedo abrir distintos fragmentos, incluido el actual (Tercia), pero con datos de otra fecha.

**Cuando, desde Calendario, vuelvo a Tercia, pero en otra fecha, el comportamiento comieza a ser anómalo**. Inicialmente, las dos opciones (Play y Calendario) aparecen en la barra superior, pero si hago clic en la opción Calendario, la opción Play se oculta y ya no navega al Calendario. Lo que debería suceder en este caso es que navegue hasta el fragmento de Calendario.

Esta es una captura de pantalla de mi barra superior cuando vuelvo al fragmento de Tercia desde el Calendario y hago clic en el botón Calendario en el menú (la opción Play desaparece):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, todavía ocurre otro problema aún más grave. Si navego a la opción Configuración (menú de tres puntos verticales) y luego vuelvo a abrir el fragmento de Tercia (desde el cual navegué a Configuración) e intento seleccionar la opción Calendario, la aplicación sale con un NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
    at org.my.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment.setPlayerButton(BreviarioDataFragment.java:342)
    at org.myapp.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment.lambda$observeIntermedia$3$org-myapp-app-ui-fragments-BreviarioDataFragment(BreviarioDataFragment.java:195)
    at org.myapp.app.ui.fragments.BreviarioDataFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
```

Dejo aquí las partes relevantes del código, por si pueden echarme una mano con esto que no logro resolver. Lo que yo quiero es:

1. Ocultar el botón de Play sea si se está reproduciendo algo, y volver a mostrarlo cuando la reproducción termine.
2. Y que funcione bien siempre, no solamente en la primera apertura del fragmento.

#### Fragmento

```
public class BreviarioDataFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeechCallback {

    private Menu mainMenu;
    private boolean isReading = false;
    private boolean isVoiceOn;
    private StringBuilder sbReader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        binding = FragmentBreviarioDataBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        setConfiguration();
        observeHour();
        return root;
    }

    private void setConfiguration() {

        mViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BreviarioViewModel.class);
        mTextView = binding.include.tvZoomable;

        progressBar = binding.progressBar;
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        float fontSize = Float.parseFloat(prefs.getString("font_size", "18"));
        mTextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, fontSize);
        hasInvitatorio=prefs.getBoolean("invitatorio",false);
        isVoiceOn = prefs.getBoolean("voice", true);
        if (isVoiceOn) {
            sbReader = new StringBuilder(VOICE_INI);
        }
        pickOutDate();
    }

    private void observeIntermedia(int hourId, String endPoint) {
        mTextView.setText(PACIENCIA);
        mViewModel.getIntermedia(mDate, hourId, endPoint).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), data -> {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (data.status == DataWrapper.Status.SUCCESS) {
                mTextView.setText(data.getData().getForView());
                if (isVoiceOn) {
                    sbReader.append(data.getData().getForRead());
                    setPlayerButton();
                }
            } else {
                mTextView.setText(Utils.fromHtml(data.getError()));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        mainMenu = menu;
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.item_voz) {
            if (mActionMode == null) {
                mActionMode =
                        requireActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            }
            readText();
            isReading = true;
            requireActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            return true;
        }

        NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
        return NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, navController)
                || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item_voz);
        if (isReading) {
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    private void setPlayerButton() {
        mainMenu.findItem(R.id.item_voz).setVisible(isVoiceOn);
    }

    //...

}
```

#### Menú (.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/item_voz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_play"
    android:visible="false"
    android:title="@string/leer"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/nav_calendario"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar_toolbar"
    android:title="@string/all_calendar"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_32dp"
        android:title="@string/title_fragment_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_32dp"
                android:title="@string/title_fragment_settings"
                app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Por si sirve, estoy usando Navigation Component:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_calendario"
    android:name="org.myapp.app.ui.fragments.CalendarioFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_fragment_calendario"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calendario" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
    android:name="org.myapp.app.ui.fragments.SettingsFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_fragment_settings"
     />
```

Para la opción Play, no navego a ninguna parte, sino que muestro una barra de progreso usando ActionMode. No hay problema en ese sentido.

Comment: Deberías considerar usar [`setVisibility(GONE)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setVisibility(int)). En cuanto al error de null, supongo que sabrás que debes verificar que lo que intentas hacer no sea sobre una variable que almacena un null.

Comment: @Mateo, al parecer este campo `private Menu mainMenu;` no es reconocido en posteriores cargas del fragmento. El NPE está ocurriendo cuando intento usarlo en  mi método `setPlayerButton()`

Comment: El NPE ocurre porque la variable no se encuentra asignada o está en `null`. Con un `if (mainMenu != null)` antes de llamar una función o acceder a un miembro del objeto te deshaces de él.